# dependency management in play

Tags: playframework

this is in my .yml file

```
require: 
    - play -> crud 
    - org.jasypt -> jasypt 1.8
```

ran play dependencies and got this message

```
~ WARNING: These dependencies are missing, your application may not 
work properl 
y (use --verbose for details), 
~ 
~       javax.security->jacc 1.0: missing artifact 
~       javax.inject->com.springsource.javax.inject 0.9.0.PFD 
~       org.springframework.security3->spring-security-core 
3.0.0.RELEASE 
~       org.springframework.security3->spring-security-web 
3.0.0.RELEASE 
~       javax.security->jaas 1.0.01: missing artifact 
~       javax.activation->activation 1.0.2: missing artifact 
~ 
***************************************************************************­** 
~ 
~ Some dependencies are still missing.
```

how do i resolve these?

Comment: does adding --verbose give you any additional information?

Answer (score 0):

Your dependencies are not found in the default repositories. You can manually add some repositories where play can search for : http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/dependency#repositories